# HTML button update .click() in Safari not working

Tags: javascript, macos, dom, bootstrap-4, safari

I'm having an issue getting Safari (14.1.2) on MacOS to register a click and make the HTML updates to a button.  The form is submitted every time but the HTML change is hit and miss. Chrome (93.0.4577.63) works as expected every time.

My button is inside a form.

```
<button type="button" id="btnFetch" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Get Earnings List</button>
```

Here is the JS

```
        $('#btnFetch').click(function() {
          $(this).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').addClass('disabled');
          $("#battery-form").submit();
        });
```

I did see another post on a fix that was a few years old that mentions something like this. I have also tried this but the click is still hit and miss in Safari. This also works as expected in Chrome.

```
    $(document).on('click', "#btnFetch" ,function(){
          $('#btnFetch').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').addClass('disabled');
          $("#battery-form").submit();

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only need the second form if the button is added to the page dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar. There is only one form on the page and the button is not added dynamically.

Comment: I meant second version of the code, the one that uses event delegation. If the element isn't added dynamically, there's little difference. The other post you saw should have explained when that version is needed, and you would have realized it doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: When you submit the form, the page reloads. This might happen before the page is rendered with the HTML change.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking the same but I have a 4 second delay in the URL load.  So the modal loads and then you can see it pauses before it goes to the URL.